# Scaling an image into the header

Tags: html, css

I am just starting to learn code and trying to make my first portfolio page project.

Sorry if this is a commonly repeated question. I've tried to search the answer on this one and found some results that have gotten me really close but not quite there and am now wondering if this is possible at all.

I want to use an image as my header but I want to fit the entire image to fit across the page without it cropping like it does when I use the 'cover' option with background-size. I've tried contain as well but that doesn't fill the whole space.

> A link to my codepen here: https://codepen.io/Lofu/pen/yXPemm

The html I'm trying to select:

```
`<div class="page-header"></div>`
```

My styling:

```
.page-header {
    background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/o3TZx8_j7FE);
    background-position: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 50vh;
    max-height: 999px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Is it possible to stretch and fit the entire image across the header that will still keep it looking relatively nice?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: So... you just want the image stretched/malformed to make sure it fits in the space in its entirety, even if the aspect ratio doesn't match?

Comment: You should use an image which matches the aspect ratio of the header but if you want to use the same image you can with background-size: 100% 100%;

Comment: Hey ya, I was trying to see if I could stretch/malform it into the space. The background-size: 100% 100% along background-repeat: no repeat; did the trick! It's doesn't quite look like what I was expecting now though, so may have to re-think this and find an image that matches the aspect ratio. Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: try using  margin: -22px 0px 21px; in .page-header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try this:

```
.page-header
{
    background-image: url("enter here your img path");
    width: auto;    
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 18.0082%; /* (img-height / img-width * container-width%) */
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

You just need the **img-height** and **img-width** normally the **container-width in % is 100**. Then you use the formal you can see as a comment behind padding-top and replace the 18.0082% with your result.

Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. Sorry I'm just a little lost while. Is the img-height / img-width * container-width% a formula? 

I found the attributes as img-height: 720px & img-width: 1080px. 
Or am I supposed to calculate the % of the image? 

Sorry if the answer is super obvious, still completely new at this

Comment: yeah, u do (img-height / img-width * container-width). For your values it is: (720 / 1080 * 100) = 66,66%. So padding-top is now 66,66%.

Comment: Thank you!! This makes it look way nicer than what I had it!